# How to access something at a known memory address?

Tags: c, memory

I know it is possible to find the memory address of a variable or function with the `&` operator. But if I know that something is at memory position `2`, how can I access it?

For instance, if I declare a pointer to `2`, it will be read as the value `2`, not the memory address `2`.

Comment: `int* x = (int*)2;` ??

Comment: Regarding the edits: you can access the revision history by clicking the "edited X ago" link under your question. There you can rollback to another version if you see fit. Note, however, that prefacing your question with a comment on its supposed stupidity is not really useful.

Comment: @Quentin. The comment is on the stupidity of changing my question without my consent nor the need to do so.

Comment: @stian No, no, I mean the "this is a stupid question, but..." part. That's not helpful to anyone. There's little chance that your reviewer will see this (there's no notification), so I'm doing the rollback.

Comment: @Quentin. Please roll back to my original question.

Comment: @stian You can do it if you really want to -- you always have full rights on your own posts. But I advise against it for the above reasons.

Comment: @stian Your question was edited so it is shorter but still as clear, removing off a verbose part, and the change was accepted by 3 people. [Better questions induces better answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); this website doesn't work like a forum.

Comment: @Asu. Maybe you should google internet forum. Well, those people are rude people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to cast it to be a pointer:

```
int *pointerToTwo = (int *)2;
```

Then you can dereference as usual:

```
int valueAtTwo = *pointerAtTwo;
```

The usual reason you'd do this kind of thing is to access memory mapped registers, in which case using the `volatile` keyword is advised:

```
int valueAtTwo = *(volatile int *)2;
```

Or maybe stick all the casting into a macro to make your code easier to read:

```
#define intValueAt(x)  (*(volatile int)(x))
int valueAtTwo = intValueAt(2);
```

Aside:  `2` is almost certainly not a valid address for this use case.  I just used it because of your reference in your question.

Comment: Note that doing this requires extra knowledge of the format of the pointers/memory addresses. In some cases, it is not a simple case of memory being addressed starting at 0 and continuing up from there. Additionally, you can attempt to access memory that is protected from read or write access. You can try to write into a ROM. You can foul up memory mapped IO devices. That being said, it can be very useful when used responsibly.

Answer (score 1):

```
void* pMemory = (void*)2L;
```

This will create a `void*` (void pointer) and set its address to `2`.

Note that if your process shouldn't be accessing that memory (you don't have permissions to read from it), this can cause all sorts of errors. Also note that you shouldn't be reading addresses at random. Using pointers to directly access memory locations is prone to errors. This is why software developers have developed so much technology to help us with only accessing the correct memory addresses under the correct circumstances using the correct expected data types.

Answer (score 1):

You can just cast it to int* to get a pointer, like this:

```
int *ptr = (int *)2;
```

Then you can access the content of 2 by normal * operator.

```
int i = *ptr;
```

will do what you want.

However, it is worth noting that in practice, the 'i' above is not the actual content of the second cell of your RAM. This is because in user-mode applications, the '2' is always treated as a virtual address and is translated (at runtime) to a physical address. Usually there is no way to do such things in user-mode codes in Unix-like OS.